# Fast Algorithm That Can Create Ulam Sequence of n Elements

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, sequence

I've been trying to solve this [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ac94db76bde60383d000038/train/javascript) on codewars.
I've got an algorithm, but it's apparently too slow to pass the test. It can create sequence of 2450 numbers in just under 1.6 seconds. I don't need the solution but the hint or something to help me to make my algorithm faster.

```
function ulamSequence(u0, u1, n) {
  // create an array with first two elements in it
  const seq = [u0, u1];
  
  // create a loop that checks if next number is valid and if it is, push it in seq
  num: for (let i = u1 + 1; seq.length < n; i++) {
    let sumCount = 0;
    for (let k = 0; k < seq.length - 1; k++) {
      if (seq.indexOf(i - seq[k]) > k && ++sumCount === 2) { continue num; }
    }
    sumCount === 1 ? seq.push(i) : "";
  }
  
  return seq;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: have an array `sums` so that `sums[N]` keeps the number of possible summations for `N`. For example, for U(1,2) `sums[3]` will be 1 and `sums[5]` will be 2 (1+4, 2+3). On each step, locate the minimal `N` so that `N > last item` and `sums[N] == 1`. Add `N` to the result, then sum it with all previous items and update `sums` accordingly.

```js
function ulam(u0, u1, len) {
    let seq = [u0, u1]
    let sums = []
    let last = u1

    sums[u0 + u1] = 1

    while (seq.length < len) {
        last += 1
        while (sums[last] !== 1) {
            last += 1
        }
        for (let n of seq) {
            let s = n + last
            sums[s] = (sums[s] || 0) + 1
        }
        seq.push(last)
    }
    return seq
}

console.time()
ulam(1, 2, 2450)
console.timeEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ulamSequence(u0, u1, n) {
  const seq = [u0, u1];
  const set = new Set(seq);

  for (let i = u1 + 2; seq.length < n; i++) {
    let sumCount = 0;
    for (let k = 0; k < seq.length - 1; k++) {
      if (set.has(i - seq[k])) {
        sumCount++;
        if (sumCount === 2) {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    if (sumCount === 1) {
      seq.push(i);
      set.add(i);
    }
  }
  return seq;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.